# Lost connection to MySQL server during query - PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have this php code, the files are hosted on another server and db else where

```
$hostname_xxx = "xxxdb.db.234141.mysqldbhosted.com";
$database_xxx = "xx11xx";
$username_xxx = "xx11xx";
$password_xxx = "xx332211xx";
$shasown = mysql_pconnect($hostname_xxx, $username_xxx, $password_xxx) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 


$your_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


echo $your_ip;



$insertSQL1 = "INSERT INTO  table (users_ip) VALUES ('$your_ip)";
mysql_select_db($database_xxx, $xxx);
$Result21 = mysql_query($insertSQL1, $xxx) or die(mysql_error());
```

**The error I am getting is**

Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: Lost connection to MySQL server during query in /domains/4444.com/html/55.php on line 8

Fatal error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query in /domains/4444.com/html/55.php on line 8

Thanks
Jean

Comment: details on this error : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: I saw this page, can I write a code that can overcome this error?

Comment: Are you sure you can connect to the remote server with the credentials you provide? And why are you using a persistent connection?

Comment: @wimvds the issue at hand is clearly not a credential issue because the connection is lost before there is even an attempt to log into the MySQL server.

Comment: This might be relevant : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php#93760, so you could try replacing the mysql_pconnect with mysql_connect to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Jean - What do you mean by "I saw this page, can I write a code that can overcome this error?" this IS YOUR OWN QUESTION?

Comment: @webfac: Hold your horses, he just says he's already seen http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html. I suggest you read that page as well, especially the 3rd item on the list of possible causes of this problem.

Comment: @everyone My sincere apologies to Jean and everyone, I misinterpreted the 2nd comment below the original post. Teaches me a lesson doesn't it! Thanks wimvds and once again, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_pconnect() creates a persistent connection to the database, whereas mysql_connect() does not. IF you are creating a persistent connection, you need only connect once throughout your session, so if you're creating a persistent connection more than once this may be the cause.

On shared servers it may be worth trying mysql_connect() over mysql_pconnect() and see if this corrects the issue at hand. Also, in your code you have:

```
$Result21 = mysql_query($insertSQL1, $xxx) or die(mysql_error());
```

But should be:

```
$Result21 = mysql_query($insertSQL1, $shasown) or die(mysql_error());
```

because $xxx was never a connection variable but $shasown is.

Personally I like to use mysqli_connect() as I find it to be a little faster.

Comment: Nope, you can use mysql_pconnect as many times as you want within your session, it will just reuse the connection you've already opened. But I wouldn't advise using persistent connections, you might run out of connections pretty quickly if you have a lot of concurrent users...

Comment: @wimvds I said "you need only connect once throughout your session" not "you CAN or MUST only connect once throughout your session"

Comment: Besides, what would be the point int calling a persistent connection over and over? You may just as well be using mysql_connect(); then.